# Compose angular configurations in angular

Tags: angular, configuration

In my angular application I need to serve some static content located in `src/cms` (only when developing locally; on production site, this content will be served by the backend). To do this I did (`angular.json`):

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "myproject": {
      "projectType": "application",
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "configurations": {
            ...
            "with-content": {
              "assets": [
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/assets",
                "src/cms"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myproject:build:with-content"
          },
          ...
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

So `ng serve` is now happily serving all the contents of `src/cms` (under `cms` path) and I'm fine with that.

Now I need to add i18n to it (pt language). And that means changing `angular.json` to add:

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "myproject": {
      "projectType": "application",
      ...
      "i18n": {
        "locales": {
          "pt": "src/locale/messages.pt.xlf"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
            "localize": true,
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            ...
            "pt": {
              "localize": ["pt"]
            },
            "with-content": {
              ...
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myproject:build:with-content"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "pt": {
              "browserTarget": "myproject:build:pt"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myproject:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

To develop the pt locale, I just run `ng serve --configuration=pt` but I lost the ability to access the static files under `cms`.

**Is it possible to compose both configurations, `with-content` and `pt` when running locally with `ng serve`?**

Or maybe, alternatively, add the `cms` path to the project, but excluding it from production build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to work with config composition (aka combined configuration).

But I could make it work by changing default and production options

#### default build options include `src/cms` (the assets we want only in local development):

```
{
  "projects": {
    "myproject": {
      "projectType": "application",
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/cms"
            ],
            ...
```

#### production options redefine assets:

```
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              ...
              "assets": [
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/assets"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
```

#### default options for local development (ng serve) use default build options:

```
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myproject:build"
          },
```

#### new configuration "pt" for local development, using the "pt" build configuration (basically stating to localize to portuguese):

```
          "configurations": {
            "pt": {
              "browserTarget": "myproject:build:pt"
            },
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CMS config is in **"with-content"** configuration and you are only serving the **pt** configuration. There are two ways around this

1. Combine configs (which is probably the one you are looking for):

   in cli: --configuration=conf1,conf2
2. The other way is having **cms** in your build options and not configurations
3. Make a new configuration with combination of the configurations you want and serve on that

Comment: When running with `--configuration=pt,cms`, it outputs an error "An unhandled exception occurred: The development server only supports localizing a single locale per build"; when running with `--configuration=cms,pt`, it starts serving the application localized to portuguese (pt), but any content loaded from `/cms` gets 404 instead.

Comment: If I had `cms` as a build option, its content would be packed on production build, and that's not what I want... the `cms` assets are to be served only for local development (localhost:4200); they are not part of the frontend. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @rslemos Did you redefine all the entries of configuration under serve?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The 2 modifications to angular.json I did are shown in the OP. Only in places I've put ellipsis there are omitted entries (for the sake of brevity and clarity). Sections without ellipsis are written in full.

Comment: I'm struggling with this same thing -- trying to avoid defining builds for every permutation of localhost options I want + culture. I'm finding combining configs with a comma does not actually work properly: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16688